# How to remove the rotation of Ar object in Sceneform Arcore

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am working on augmented reality application where I have place an 3d object,but I have a requirement that it should not be rotated but should be scalable . How to disable roation of object?

Answer (score 0):

Rotation happens because of the RotationManipulator.cs inside the Manipulators under scripts.

So you can just disable the call to the script,and it wont rotate.